# How to standardize column in pandas

Tags: python, regex, pandas

I have dataframe which contains `id` column with the following sample values

```
16620625 5686

16310427-5502

16501010 4957

16110430 8679

16990624/4174
  
16230404.1177

16820221/3388
```

I want to  standardise to XXXXXXXX-XXXX (i.e. 8 and 4 digits separated by a dash), How can I achieve that using python.

here's my code

```
df['id']
df.replace(" ", "-")
```

Comment: `df['id'] = df['id'].str.replace(r"\D+", "-", regex=True)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can use [DataFrame.replace()](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.replace.html) function using a regular expression like this:

```
df = df.replace(regex=r'^(\d{8})\D(\d{4})$', value=r'\1-\2')
```

Here's example code with sample data.

```python
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'id': [
            '16620625 5686',
            '16310427-5502',
            '16501010 4957',
            '16110430 8679',
            '16990624/4174',
            '16230404.1177',
            '16820221/3388']})

# normalize matching strings with 8-digits + delimiter + 4-digits
df = df.replace(regex=r'^(\d{8})\D(\d{4})$', value=r'\1-\2')
print(df)
```

**Output:**

```
              id
0  16620625-5686
1  16310427-5502
2  16501010-4957
3  16110430-8679
4  16990624-4174
5  16230404-1177
6  16820221-3388
```

If any value does not match the regexp of the expected format then it's value will not be changed.

Answer (score 0):

inside a for loop:

1. convert your data frame entry to a string.
2. traverse this string up to 7th index.
3. concatenate '-' after 7th index to the string.
4. concatenate remaining string to the end.
5. traverse to next data frame entry.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).